# Anybody implemented IceLink in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, webrtc, videochat, websync

I am going to develop an application which includes Audio/Video/Text chat.

I read [IceLink documentation and demo](https://docs.frozenmountain.com/icelink3/gettingstarted/). From that what I understood is we need to do signalling using [WebSync](https://www.frozenmountain.com/products-services/websync/) to connect two peers.

But I couldn’t understand how to do it.

My questions are (suppose A wants to call B):
1. How A knows the address of B (whatever it may be like, ID or anything)
2. How B comes to know that A is calling him/her

Answer (score 3):

We once build an App with P2P Connection via IceLink.
But we didn´t use the WebSync Component.

To establish a RTC Connection you need a non-P2P communcation to do the Handshake first.
With this Handshake all neccessary information is transmitted, and icelink can try to reach the other peer.
We used Microsoft SignalR for that since it is a serverside-javascript which can push messages to connected clients.

1.this is part of the handshake

2.Signaling via SignalR (e.g.)

Comment: You said _With this Handshake all neccessary information is transmitted_ , so which information should be transmit?

Comment: When you create an offer, icelink generates some information about the network (IPAdresses, Ids, etc.). This offer you have to send to your Server, a client can then respont to this offer with similar information.

Comment: Do we need to create offer based on Peer we wants to connect or its independent?

Comment: This is up to you.
You can dedicate RTC Offers to a specific username. Then the Server can send the offer to the registered device which is used by this user.

Comment: This might be useful
[Icelink docs](http://docs.frozenmountain.com/icelink2/index.html#class=icelink-diagrams-signalling)

Comment: In documentation(https://docs.frozenmountain.com/icelink3/gettingstarted/Signalling.html) they said that _Peer-to-peer links will be created automatically to peers that join the same channel_. So chat is only possible with channel mechanism?

Comment: May I have personal WhatsApp number?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139970/discussion-between-jagruttam-panchal-and-norman-schutt).

Comment: I think that WebSync does create links to peers, but this will not happen if you use an alternative signaling mechanism.
As I said, I didn´t use WebSync.

Comment: Thank you so much Friend! :)

Comment: Friend please help me. I am helpless as I can't find help anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I followed their example and achieved the same thing as you are intending to. 
You need to handle call making on the server-side and somehow communicate the session id to another user . as simple as that.

Comment: I found another SDK. And its too better than IceLink and also provides best quality for calling. [CometChat] (https://www.cometchat.com/)